Response headers not being set in Crow a C++ web framework
I am working on a reverse-proxy server, using the crow framework in C++. I want to set the headers that i get after fetching the original server but it does not work. I receive 9 headers from original server but only 4 are added to current headers.
CROW_CATCHALL_ROUTE(Server)([](const crow::request& req, crow::response& res) {
    string ip = get_server_ip(REQUEST_COUNT, IP_POOL);
    auto op = fetch_response_from_ip(ip, req.raw_url, PORT);

    if (op) {
        res.code = op->status;
        res.body = op->body;
        if (req.raw_url != "/") {
            for (const auto& header : op->headers) {
                //std::cout << "Header: " << header.first << ": " << header.second << std::endl;
                res.set_header(header.first, header.second);
            }
        }
        // All headers set in the response are being logged correctly but they are not present when checked in the networks tab in dev tools 
        // and file contents are missing. I receive 9 headers from original server but only 4 are added to current headers 
        std::cout << "Headers set in response:" << std::endl;
        for (const auto& header : res.headers) {
            std::cout << header.first << ": " << header.second << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        res.code = 502; // Bad Gateway
        res.write("Failed to forward request: Unexpected Error Occurred !");
    }
    cout << endl << "BODY: === " << endl << op->body << endl;
    res.end();

});

I am looping through all the received headers and setting them for my new Response, just to ensure they are set, i log them as well and it works fine but the headers are not added to the response. I tried add_header method and also manually inserting values with .insert methods but nothing worked. All files received are empty.
LOGS:
(2024-07-29 13:05:07) [INFO    ] Response: 0000020B43D25590 /_next/static/css/4cd4294a4f81ba5a.css 200 0
IP:Success (no error) (0)
IP:Success (no error) (0)
Headers set in response:
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Headers set in response:
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
ETag: Content-Type: W/"2526f-18eff52d3f1"
Connection: application/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: close
Content-Length: public, max-age=31536000, immutable
ETag: W/"ea4-190efe7a1ce"
Connection: close
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 3748152175
Date: Mon, 29 Jul 2024 13:05:07 GMT

Browser network tab:

IDK but reading the documentation set_header - sets the value of an existing header and, add_header - adds a new header. Maybe you should be using add_header when the header in question does not already exist.

\[\] in CROW_CATCHALL_ROUTE(Server)(\[\](const crow::request& req, ... looks fishy. What are the backslashes doing there?

copy pasting error, they are not present

i tried add_header method and also manually inserting values but nothing worked

Edit the question and share the logs please.

sure added logs and headers screenshot as well
